# Thymeleaf render model attribute prior it set in controller method

Tags: thymeleaf

When I hit `/repairOnlineHome` url thymeleaf render wizardStep as not initialized despite it initialized in showRepairStep1().

If on next step I hit `/repairOnlineHome2` url thymeleaf render wizardStep with value set in previous showRepairStep1() i.e. wizardStep equal 1.

What's really surprise me that it looks like thymeleaf call getter for wizardStep before controller method set correct value.

```
@Controller
public class RepairController {

    private Integer wizardStep;// = new Integer(1);

    @ModelAttribute("wizardStep")
    public Integer wizardStep(){
        return wizardStep;
    }

@RequestMapping({"/repairOnlineHome"})
public String showRepairStep1(final SeedStarter seedStarter) {
    seedStarter.setDatePlanted(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    wizardStep = 1;
    return "repairOnlineHome";
}

@RequestMapping({"/repairOnlineHome2"})
public String showRepairStep2(final SeedStarter seedStarter) {
    seedStarter.setDatePlanted(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    wizardStep = 2;
    return "repairOnlineHome2";
}
...
}
```

In html I render wizardStep as

```
<div>WizardStep: <span th:text="${wizardStep}">wizardStepNo</span></div>
```

My question is: Why thymeleaf render model attribute prior it set in controller method and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that @ModelAttribute methods are invoked before the controller methods annotated with @RequestMapping are invoked.

So , I commented out wizardStep() and switch to

```
@RequestMapping({"/repairOnlineHome"})
public String showRepairStep1(Model model, final SeedStarter seedStarter) {
    wizardStep = 1;
    model.addAttribute("wizardStep", wizardStep);
    return "repairOnlineHome";
}
```